# mistake in code: message queue not receiving the value

Tags: c, posix

my queue is sending the message but it doesnt receive...

Can anyone please help with the problem.

Editor note: improved code formatting, but need more details

---

Code:

```
#define MAXSIZE     128

void die(char *s)
{
  perror(s);
  exit(1);
}

struct msgbuf
{
    int    mtype;
    char    mtext[MAXSIZE];
};
```

-> main()

```
main()
{
    int msqid;
    int msgflg = IPC_CREAT | 0666;
    key_t key;
    struct msgbuf sbuf;
     struct msgbuf rcvbuffer;
    int buflen;
    srand(time(0));
    key = rand()%(100+40);
    printf("%d",key);
```

Get the message queue ID for the given key

```
    if ((msqid = msgget(key, msgflg )) < 0)   //Get the message queue ID for the given key
      die("msgget");

    //Message Type
    sbuf.mtype = 1;

    printf("Enter a message to add to message queue : ");
    scanf("%[^\n]",sbuf.mtext);
    getchar();

    buflen = strlen(sbuf.mtext) + 1 ;

    if (msgsnd(msqid, &sbuf, buflen, IPC_NOWAIT) < 0)
    {
       printf ("%d, %d, %s, %d\n", msqid, sbuf.mtype, sbuf.mtext, buflen);
        die("msgsnd");
    }

    else
        printf("Message Sent\n");
    printf("%d",msqid);
    exit(0);


    if ((msqid = msgget(key, 0666)) < 0)
      die("msgget()");
```

Receive an answer of message type 1.

```
     //Receive an answer of message type 1.
    if (msgrcv(msqid, &rcvbuffer, MAXSIZE, 1, 0) < 0)
      die("msgrcv");

    printf("%s\n", rcvbuffer.mtext);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Just put `//` everywhere instead of `enter code here`, and it should be mostly correct.

Comment: Characters are entering my brain but it doesn't receive...

Comment: @aneena I tried to edit your post to make it correct (code formatting) but we need more details ... can you add some and format you code? (: (so I added "useless" lines, like "Receive an answer of message type 1." in order to be able to validate the edit, even if it cuts your code)

Answer (score 0):

It took me a few moments, but I found your error. The type checking of message queues depends on an mtype field of type long and not int.

If you simply receive the message without specifying the type, it would come through. But if you specify the type, it won't because the "mtype" field in your "struct msgbuf" is of type int and not of type long. (On my - and most probably yours as well - architecture, there is a 4-byte difference between the two)

Change the type of mtype in your struct msgbuf to long and it will work...